# Grouping Output Data After Having Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, having-clause

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and stuck on SQL coding.

I have the following columns Year, Month and Active and here is some small sample data below:

```
Year Month Active
2005  Feb     Y
2005  May     Y
2006  Nov     Y
2007  Jul     Y
2008  Jan     Y
2008  Mar     Y
```

I want to bring back the years that have 2 or more 'Active' months (HAVING Active > 2) within the year. So from this data, I want to bring back the years: 2005 and 2008.

I wanted the data to read like so:

```
Year   Month
2005  Feb, May
2008  Jan, Mar
```

How do I go about this? I know how to Group and use Count function, but I know there's a better to get the data to look like above. And I need to do all this in 1 query.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte` with *window* function :

```
with cte as ( 
      select *
      from (select *, count(*) over (partition by year) c
            from table 
           ) t
      where c > 1
)
select Year,
       stuff( (select ','+Month
               from cte c1
               where c.year = c1.year 
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as Month
from cte c
group by Year;
```

The preceding query uses `xml` method with help of `stuff()` function to grab the rows into single field. However, if you have any plan for upgrading your SQL Server, then you will have a very short way via [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function instead of `xml + stuff()` .

Answer (score 0):

You could do your group by and having in a derived table.  This will give you the years that have multiple active months.  Then you can use a subquery to get the months from your table that have the same year as the years in your derived table.  FOR XML PATH('') will convert the values into a comma separated string and STUFF will just remove the leading comma and space.

```
select  Year, 
        stuff((select ', ' + Month
               from     Table1 t1
               where    t1.Year = dt.Year 
               for xml path(''))
               ,1,2,'') as Month
From    (
            select      Year 
            from        Table1 
            where       Active = 'Y'
            group by    Year
            having      count(*) > 1
        ) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select Year,
       stuff( (select ','+Month
               from YourTable c1
               where c.year = c1.year 
               for xml path('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as Month
from YourTable c
group by Year
Having SUM(CASE WHEN Active='Y' THEN 1 Else 0 END)>=2;
```

Comment: `#tab1` *and* `YourTable`?

Comment: its a mistake. Corrected